# How to not execute some php 7 code on php 5.6?

Tags: php, if-statement, php-7, php-5.6, spaceship-operator

recently i had the necessity of use come code for backward compatibility with PHP 5.6 and i did this using if statement, checking php version for choosing what code execute.
This is a little example:

```
if ( version_compare( PHP_VERSION, '7.0', '>=' ) ) {
    return strtotime($b['date']) <=> strtotime($a['date']);
}
else {
    if (strtotime($a['date']) == strtotime($b['date'])) {
        return 0;
    }
    return (strtotime($a['date']) > strtotime($b['date'])) ? -1 : 1;
}
```

I thought that this would be sufficient, but it's not. PHP is still trying to execute the PHP 7 code, returning an error with the spaceship operator. Anyone know why php is still executing code inside and if statement that clearly says to not do that and how to solve this? Thank you

Comment: When you say it's executing, it will always try and parse any code in a source file, this doesn't mean it's executed it, just that it has encountered the code.

Comment: @NigelRen Ok, so it's trying to parse the code and encounter this unkown spaceship operator.. How i could prevent parsing of that code, preserving 5.6 compatibility and 7.0 functionality in base of wich version is installed?

Comment: You could move the code to a separate file and use `include` for the code for php 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are trying won't work because the parser will still try to parse the entire file and won't recognize some of the php7 syntax. To prevent this you would need to do something like this:

```
if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '7.0', '>=')) {
    include('php7code.php');
}
else {
    include('php5code.php');
}
```

Note that this is not advisable and will make your code harder to test.

Comment: Thank you, i think it's unfortunately time to remove some backward compatibility..